# Error installing pg, requires Ruby version >= 2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

```
gem install pg
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
pg requires Ruby version >= 2.2.
```

This happened after I installed a newer version of PG on my system, so I figure that's fine, what's happening is that it's installing `gem pg` using the config from the newer version of Postgres that I installed with Homebrew.

So I figure I'll just install the gem using the older version of PG that I had before.

```
brew install postgresql@9.6
Error: postgresql@9.6 9.6.14 is already installed
```

Ok perfect! So I then located the `pg_config` file and am trying to install the `gem pg` using that config:

```
gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.6/9.6.14/bin/pg_config

ERROR:  Error installing pg:
pg requires Ruby version >= 2.2.
```

Yet the error persists... any help appreciated... I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling PG a number of times now...

Also something else that's super frustrating... is there a list somewhere that shows what versions of PG are compatible with which versions of Ruby? I feel like every few months I run into this problem and have this frustrating search happening...

```
ruby --version
> ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin13.0]
which ruby
> /Users/jamesdong/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby
which gem
> /Users/jamesdong/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/gem
```

Comment: Run `ruby --version`, `which ruby`, and `which gem` and post your paths. You're on macOS, using homebrew, and it looks like you're using (inadvertently or not) the system ruby. Are you using rvm at all? If not, you should be using a ruby version manager such as asdf or rvm to install a newer version of ruby (and not use the macOS system ruby)

Comment: @JayDorsey thanks posted. I am using rvm, but for the purposes of this app, I'd like to NOT have to update ruby. and it definitely had worked before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Changelog](https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg/blob/master/History.rdoc#v120-2019-12-20-michael-granger-gedfaeriemudorg), pg 1.2.0 removed support for Ruby <= 2.2. Since you're using 2.1 you'll want to `gem install pg -v 1.1.4`, the previous version

(I don't think the actual postgres version you're using should matter as much, 1.1.4 appears to support at least up to 11.x)